# filter groups where max value is greater than limit

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a dataframe(tsibble) with the following characteristics. There are other STAT_NAME's with lower max's also.

```
 STAT_NAME                                              max
 DB time                                       83487.082433
 sql execute elapsed time                      83322.591389
 DB CPU                                        63712.585025
 PL/SQL execution elapsed time                   620.239918
 hard parse (sharing criteria) elapsed time      215.748621
```

I would like to keep the STAT_NAME's(groups) with max greater than 500 or some specific limit as appropriate. In this case 500. I see examples to find the max row but I'm trying to eliminate the groups with very low values. Pretty much a noise filter. I need to keep the groups that have high peaks since this is performance data. Eliminating the groups that have "very small" values. Time based if that's useful information.

Something like:

tsallstm has

```
SNAP_TIME           STAT_NAME                     SECONDS
2021-02-16 13:31:42 PL/SQL execution elapsed time    .303316
2021-02-16 13:31:42 DB CPU                        158.935656
2021-02-16 13:31:42 sql execute elapsed time      165.082876
2021-02-16 13:31:42 DB time                       345.022309
2021-02-16 14:01:42 PL/SQL execution elapsed time     .28558
2021-02-16 14:01:42 sql execute elapsed time      158.518897
2021-02-16 14:01:42 DB CPU                        165.750627
2021-02-16 14:01:42 DB time                       347.531669
2021-02-16 14:31:42 PL/SQL execution elapsed time    .297387
2021-02-16 14:31:42 sql execute elapsed time      190.519756
2021-02-16 14:31:42 DB CPU                        209.100002
2021-02-16 14:31:42 DB time                       443.938258
```

newtsibble <- tsallstm %<%
filter(groupswithvalues where maxgroupvalue > lowerlimitvalue)

John

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to share the data

Comment: well that came out ugly, let me figure out how to reformat

Comment: Don't worry too much about the ugly of `dput` it serve the purpose ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first group by STAT_NAME, then the `max` calc inside the `filter` line below will find the max SECONDS within each group (removing, in this case, any NA's). That way you'll get the group's max, and the filter will include any item where it's group's max > 500.

```
tsallstm %>%
  group_by(STAT_NAME) %>%
  filter(max(SECONDS, na.rm = TRUE) > 500) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Looks like that works!! trying to decide if the ungroup is actually needed or not. I was almost there, thanks for the push over the edge!